# Double escaped unicode URL

Tags: python, json, parsing, unicode

I am parsing JSON with cjson library in python. On of the field has text that contains escaped URL like this: `http:\/\/domain.com\/index.html`. However, when I parse the field using cjson, I get a Unicode object that looks like this:

```
`u'Payload text http:\\/\\/domain.com\\/index.html'`
```

Looks like the URL is escaped twice(?) I tried to decode it but I always get same result. For example:

```
payload['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('string_escape')
```

This returns the same response, double escaped URL. What should I do? I know I am making some conceptual error here, and not aware of how unicode encoding works.

Answer (score 0):

If you print `u'Payload text http:\\/\\/domain.com\\/index.html'`, you'll see that the result is `Payload text http:\/\/domain.com\/index.html`.  It's not doubly-escaped, you're seeing the `repr` of the string rather than the literal value.